# custom structural directive not working when the selector name is not ttIf

Tags: angular

I have written an custom structural directive

```
    import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[ttIf]'
    })
    export class ApphighlightStrucDirective {

      _visible: boolean = false;
      constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

      @Input()
      set ttIf(condition: boolean) {
        this._visible = condition
        this._updateView();
      }

      _updateView(): void {
        if (this._visible) {
          this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }
        else {
          this.vcRef.clear();
        }
      }
    }
```

using in the appcomponent

```
<div *ttIf="available">
  Using the ttIf directive
</div>
```

If we use ttIf as selector, div is shown or hidden. but if the selector name is different eg:visbleIf

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[visbleIf]'
})
<div *visbleIf="available">
  Using the ttIf directive
</div>
```

getting this error
p.component.html:9 NG0303: Can't bind to 'visbleIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 'AppComponent' component template).

1. If 'div' is an Angular component and it has the 'visbleIf' input, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
   r

what could the reason for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining structural directive, the input and directive names should be the same because the input property is used to pass data into the directive.

Rename your structural directive input

**From**

```
@Input() ttIf ===>
```

**To**

```
@Input() visbleIf(condition: boolean)
```

**Updated Code**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[visbleIf]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ApphighlightStrucDirective {
  _visible: boolean = false;
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  @Input()
  set visbleIf(condition: boolean) {
    this._visible = condition;
    this._updateView();
  }

  _updateView(): void {
    if (this._visible) {
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.vcRef.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnogj9?file=src/tttif.ts)**